# Restore Ubuntu using Systemback SBLive file

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, backup, restore, systemback

I need to restore my Ubuntu OS to an earlier time period. I have been suing Systemback to save backups of my system periodically. The problem is that `.sblive` files are created instead of the `.iso` because of the 4GB limit. How can I use the `.sblive` file I have to restore my OS?

Answer (score 1):

Just write the .sblive file to a USB key, with Systemback.

Then boot this pendrive and start the Systemback. Perform a system copy without partition formatting. This is the simplest method.

*Note* The .sblive file must be in your /home/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution:

To generate the ISO file:

```
mkisofs -iso-level 3 -r -V sblive -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -c isolinux/boot.cat -o sblive.iso sblive
```

pd: Install mkisofs from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtools/

i don't prove it yet but it worth to try

I find this solution here:
https://answers.launchpad.net/systemback/+question/273061

Comment: `mkisofs` is included in the `genisoimage` package. No need to install anything from source.